# Football: Can player enter twice?

Tags: rules, football

In an official football match, if a player has been substituted, can that player enter in the match again (the trainer must use another substitution)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, no. To quote from the [2015-16 Laws of the Game](http://www.thefa.com/~/media/files/pdf/the%20fa%202015-16/laws-of-the-game-2015-16.ashx), page 19:

> the substituted player takes no further part in the match

There is however a note on page 18:

> The use of return substitutions is only permitted in the lowest levels (grassroots/recreational) of football, subject to the agreement of the member association concerned.